# Problem installing PHPUnit in Windows using PEAR and without PEAR also

Tags: phpunit

I have tried connecting to pear.phpunit.de and three other similar connections using PEAR, but could not due to connection timeout, after updating connection also in PEAR, no progress.

Also, I have tried installing PHPunit without PEAR by changing @PHPBIN@ in phpunit.php file and renaming it, then cannot run it as an executable file in DOS (chmod does'nt work in DOS, was written in steps, which i followed)

Is there any other simple way to get PHPUnit working in Windows under Wamp server. Please respond, all things hanging on it presently.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
pear clear-cache
pear update-channels
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

If PHPUnit installs, but you still can't run a unit test, you might have to move the phpunit file down one directory. So if your php.exe file is in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.11\ you should have something like this:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.11\phpunit.bat
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.11\phpunit
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.11\PEAR\phpunits
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pear config-set temp_dir D:\temp
```

the problem is that whitespaces in the path of the temp dir prevents pear from installing the package.

Also try to empty the pear cache directory (somewhere in %appdata% local temp).

Answer (score 0):

As of December 31 2014 pear.phpunit.de will be shut down, so here is another way of configuring PHPUnit on your machine:

- First, make sure that you are able to execute "php --version" from Command Prompt without getting an error. If you do get an error, add the path to "php.exe" to your PATH environment variable (mine is under "C:\xampp\php" for example)
- Download "phpunit.phar" from https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
- Move this file to a folder in which you wish to keep the phpunit installation (I'll use "C:\phpunit" in this example)
- Create a new text file under "C:\phpunit\" and rename it to "phpunit.cmd"
- Right-click and open "phpunit.cmd" in edit mode, copy>paste the following line and save the file:

  > @php"%~dp0\phpunit.phar" %*
- At this point you should have "phpunit.cmd" and "phpunit.phar" under "C:\phpunit"
- Go to your system variables and edit your PATH variable
- Add this line to the very beginning of your PATH variable and don't forget the semicolon:

  > C:\phpunit;
- Click OK to save the edit, Open Command Prompt and type "phpunit --version"﻿